# Проблемма применения lut фильтров (.cube) на Golang

Tags: golang, обработка-изображений

Я пытаюсь применить lut фильтр к картике, но результат получается совершенно не такой, который должен быть.

Пример lut файла

```
#LUT size
LUT_3D_SIZE 32

#data domain
DOMAIN_MIN 0.0 0.0 0.0
DOMAIN_MAX 1.0 1.0 1.0

#LUT data points
0.000000 0.007507 0.005585
0.007141 0.007660 0.005768
0.020630 0.007843 0.006012
0.035492 0.008087 0.006256
0.052155 0.008362 0.006561
0.071411 0.008698 0.006958
0.093903 0.009125 0.007385
0.120270 0.009613 0.007935
0.151215 0.010254 0.008667

...

0.929077 1.000000 1.000000
0.948395 1.000000 1.000000
0.965790 1.000000 1.000000
0.981720 1.000000 1.000000
0.996429 1.000000 1.000000
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

Исходное изображение
[image: Исходное изображение]

Полученное изображение
[image: Исходное изображение]

Из чего я сделал вывод, что скорее всего неправильно понимаю как получать цвет для замены из lut файла.

Вот код

```
type MyImg struct {
    image.Image
    custom map[image.Point]color.Color
}

// get MyImg object
func NewMyImg(img image.Image) *MyImg {
    return &MyImg{img, map[image.Point]color.Color{}}
}

// set color
func (m *MyImg) Set(x, y int, c color.Color) {
    m.custom[image.Point{x, y}] = c
}

// get color
func (m *MyImg) At(x, y int) color.Color {
    // Explicitly changed part: custom colors of the changed pixels:
    if c := m.custom[image.Point{x, y}]; c != nil {
        return c
    }
    // Unchanged part: colors of the original image:
    return m.Image.At(x, y)
}

// using lut filter and write to the new image
func lutCorrection(myImg MyImg, lut []string, newImgPath string) {
    bounds := myImg.Image.Bounds()

    // Что бы получить новое значение для каждого пикселя нужно 
    // преобразовать значения rgb так что бы они были не больше 32(в 
    // данном случае)

    // myImg.At(x, y).RGBA() - возвращает значения от 0 до 65535, потому 
    // для их преобразования делаю
    // math.Cbrt(float64(len(lut))) == 32 в данном случае

    n := 65536 / math.Cbrt(float64(len(lut)))


    for y := 0; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
        for x := 0; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {
        curR, curG, curB, curA := myImg.At(x, y).RGBA()

        var r, g, b, a float64

            // получаем значения в нужном виде

        r = float64(curR) / n
        g = float64(curG) / n
        b = float64(curB) / n

            // высчитываю координату
        coord := float64(r) * float64(g) * float64(b)

            // получаю rgb для замены
        lutRGB := lut[uint(coord)]
        newRGB := strings.Split(lutRGB, " ")

        // парсинг строки в числа
        var newR, newG, newB float64

        if newR, err = strconv.ParseFloat(newRGB[0], 64); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

        if newG, err = strconv.ParseFloat(newRGB[1], 64); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

        if newB, err = strconv.ParseFloat(newRGB[2], 64); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

            // преобразование полученных значений в формат от 0 до 255
        newR *= 255
        newG *= 255
        newB *= 255

            // замена пикселя
            myImg.Set(x, y, color.RGBA{uint8(newR), uint8(newG), uint8(newB), uint8(a)})
        }
    }

    // создание новой кртинки 
    outFile, err := os.Create(newImgPath)
    defer outFile.Close()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error can not create file: ", err.Error())
        return
    }

    jpeg.Encode(outFile, &myImg, nil)
}
```

В чем я ошибаюсь?